# How to accept user input during a mocha test (NodeJs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

I am using mocha and chai to test all the REST-APIs in my project.
The issue is that for user registration, I send an activation code on the user's email id.
Therefore to test "Activation API call", I need to enter the activation code by hand in the console.
But it makes the test go out of time.

My temporary solution:

```
describe('User API calls', function () {
    this.timeout(30000);

    it('should should successfully activate user', done => { //Needs user intervention
        console.log('You have less than 30 seconds to enter!');
        const activationCode = readlineSync.question('What is the activation code? ');
        chai.request(configs.url)
            .get('/user/activation')
            .query({'code': activationCode})
            .end((err, res) => {
                expect(res.body).to.haveOwnProperty('success');
                done();
            });
    });
}
```

This has an obvious limitation though as if I take more than 30 seconds to input the activation code on the console, the test will fail because of timeout.

Can someone please suggest a solution or a better workaround?

Comment: You can read about mocking (https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/mocks/). Entering the code is defintely not a good idea in unit test cases.

Comment: @AshishModi Thanks for your comment. However, in my case mocking is not an option as my test cases are just trying to test the APIs. I don't have access to the actual code or logic inside.
Also, I am aware that it's not a good practice to take user inputs, but I don't think I have an alternative here.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try and answer this with limited information about your API. Wouldn't this test make more sense if you would include the register call also? You await the register request, and use that response for the "/user/activation" request.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
It won't work in my case as the response for register request does not contain the "Security Code". It is sent only to the email id.